# What is the best way of converting a Microsoft Word document into XHTML?

Tags: php, xhtml, ms-word

I would like to programatically convert a Microsoft Word document into XHTML. The language of choice is PHP, so I would appreciate any suggestions with PHP.

The initial idea is trying to convert the doc file into odt, and then use the [Odt2Xhtml](http://odt2xhtml.eu.org/index_en.html) PHP class to get it into XHTML format.

Any better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're running Linux one way to go would be to install OpenOffice on the server.

Example instructions for a 'headless' (i.e. no UI) install can be found [here](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=6691).

You could then use a nice CLI app like [unoconv](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/) executed via shell_exec to do your conversions via PHP.

Answer (score 2):

The most robust way is to [use COM to let Word save the document as HTML](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/02/19.html).

I don't know whether Word can generate XHTML directly; if not, Google shows [plenty of options](http://www.google.com/search?q=convert+HTML+to+XHTML) for doing that conversion.

Comment: Not especially robust: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;257757

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.codeplex.com/OpenXMLViewer which includes an XSLT you could adapt, which is what I did in docx4j.  Note however, that that XSLT is not for the faint of heart!

Answer (score 0):

**phpLiveDocx** offers a really easy way to convert Microsoft Word documents.

Learn more at the project web site:

http://www.phplivedocx.org

You can also use phpLiveDocx to merge textual data with MS Word templates and save the resulting document to DOC, DOCX, RTF, PDF or TXT.

The component is enterprise-ready and has been written for the Zend Framework.